# Prove $\sum_{r=1}^n (r+1)2^r = (a+bn)2^n$ by induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

> It is a conjectured that $$\sum_{r=1}^n (r+1)2^r = (a+bn)2^n$$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants. If the conjecture is true, verify that $a=0$ and $b=2$ and prove the result by induction.

I have no idea how I would go about verifying the values for $a$ and $b$, so would someone be able to help me get started on that.

I have attempted the proof by induction, where my inductive step doesn't seem quite right to me. My workings are below is there anything wrong with it?

If $n=k$
$$ \sum_{r=1}^{k}(r+1)2^r = 2^k(2k)$$
If $n=k+1$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=1}^{k+1}(r+1)2^r &= \sum_{r=1}^{k}(r+1)2^r + 2^{k+1}(k+2)\\
{}&=2^k(2k) + 2^{k+1}(k+2)\\
&=2^k(2k+2(k+2))\\
&=2^k(4k+4)\\
&=2^{k+1}(2(k+1))\\
&=2^n(2n)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The case $n=0$ gives $0=a$; the case $n=1$ gives $4=(a+b)2\implies b=2$. Now prove the sum is $n2^{n+1}$ by induction. I don't know why you have misgivings; your inductive step is fine. (We needn't check the base step, since the calculations above already did.)